# Gray Box thumbnail icon Google Play Developer Console

Tags: android, google-play, icons, google-play-developer-api, developer-console

i have a problem in the Google Play Developer Console.
After i had uploaded a new update of one of my apps, the thumbnail icon of this app in the "All Applications" page changed to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iqvpw.png). I had set a different icon both on android manifest and "Store listing" page.

Comment: All my icons returned to normal in the past hour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same thumbnail for my app [as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyPy1.png), for which I published an update one hour ago. This was a staged release, so it might be a new symbol indicating such a staged release.

Comment: I also noticed that since this icon has appeared a lot of in-app purchases of my app give the "Payment declined" status. I don't know if this thing is connected in some way with the gray box thumbnail icon or is it just a case

Comment: The icon shows up on all my in app purchases, both Charged and Payment Declined. So don't worry, the icon should not be visible in any way to the users of your app

Comment: I can see again the original thumbnail. It seems that they fixed the bug.

Comment: I can verify the fixed it for my app as well. Bug looks fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same thumbnail icon in my console, and I used both 'old' APK page and the 'new' Manage Release page. Even after my updates have been published to Play and become visible to the users, the grey box does not go away.

But since the apk update has gone well, this is not a problem and would be fixed soon. It does not seem to communicate any 'stage' of the rollout, though

UPD I watched an explanatory video about the new Manage Releases page but it does not explain the 'grey box' mystery

Comment: The grey box is gone )

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a new issue which appeared in the last hours... I did not make a staged release and I have got this strange icon anyway. It will probably not disturb my app on the store (I hope... :) ).

Answer (score 0):

The icon appeared in my console after I uploaded a new APKs with launch icons for high density screens

Comment: Could you please tell in which folder you have pasted High Density launch icon. I hope xxxhdpi ?

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I have updated my app and Yes the mysterious Gray box has not even left me.

Here is **Google group discussing** the same: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-discuss/mJAn1oGRZpQ

According to **Peter**

> It turns out my hdpi icon was 57x57 instead of being the correct size. 
>   Fixing the size and adding a mdpi version for good measure seems to 
>   have fixed the issue. Strange how only the website is bothered by it 
>   but I guess it was my own fault for not bothering to perform what 
>   seemed like an unnecessary resize when I started the app.

I'll try to do the same for my next update, may be in time Google solve the issue, I'm also going to report this to Google.

Update: Seems like issue resolved, I got back my app icon back without applying any changes(29/3/2017)