# Grey Box in Google Play Developer Console

Tags: android, google-play

I just submitted an update to Google Play, and now I am seeing an empty grey box next to my app name in the Google Play Developer console. I have submitted countless updates to Google Play, and I have never seen this. In the play store, the icon shows up fine. Does anyone know what this could possibly be? Is this a new feature of Google Play while the app is being distributed, or did I possibly mess something up in my latest release. Thank you in advance.[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gray Box thumbnail icon Google Play Developer Console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43056304/gray-box-thumbnail-icon-google-play-developer-console)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those wondering, this was a bug with Google. They have since fixed it and the icon has gone back to normal.